# Exclusive XPath test

Tags: xpath, schematron

I'm trying to write a Schematron rule to perform the following test...

If no li under root contains "abc" and root contains title, "def" then report.

The problem that I'm having is that I am getting many false positives. Here is my current XPath...

```
<rule context="li">
                <assert test="not(contains(text(),'abc')) and ancestor::root/descendant::title = 'def'">Report this.</assert>
            </rule>
```

My output ends up reporting on each li that does not contain "abc" which I understand since it is testing every li and reporting.

However, I don't know how to write the XPath so that I can test if any li contains "abc".

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show sample XML that gives a false positive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as you hinted at, is that you've expressed this in Schematron as a rule that applies to each `li` element; whereas the rule you've described in English is one that applies to each `root` element.

So you could express it as

```
<rule context="root">
  <assert test=".//li[contains(text(),'abc')] or
                not(.//title = 'def')">Report this.</assert>
</rule>
```

Note that I've flipped the sense of the test, to match your English description

> If no li under root contains "abc" and root contains title, "def" then report.

Since you're using an `<assert>` element, you assert the opposite of what you want to report. It might make more sense to use a `<report>` element:

```
<rule context="root">
  <report test="not(.//li[contains(text(),'abc')]) and
                .//title = 'def'">Report this.</report>
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. I figured I had the logic switched some how. Correct answer!

Comment: @Jeff Glad to be of help. Schematron rocks!